# Camunda Disable DbHistoryEventHandler on Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda

Hello I'm new at camunda and now I'm migrating camunda from 3.4 to 7.14, I want to disable DbHistoryEventHandler so it won't write to history table (https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.14/update/minor/712-to-713/#changed-behavior-for-custom-historyeventhandler), but the problem is I can't found **enableDefaultDbHistoryEventHandler** on spring boot camunda engine properties (https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.14/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/configuration/#camunda-engine-properties), can anyone please help me regarding this.

Comment: What are the steps you followed in migration camunda 3.x to 7.x. I was planning to do the same. Will it impace the instances which are running and what are the database schema updates which I have to follow?

Answer (score 2):

Already found the answer, for everyone facing this problem you can disable it on your spring boot application.yaml by adding this

```
  camunda.bpm:
    generic-properties:
      properties:
        enableDefaultDbHistoryEventHandler: false
```

reference: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.14/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/configuration/#generic-properties